# ZXing Barcode Scanner for Webapps

Tags: javascript, android, webview, barcode, zxing

I'm trying to use http://zxing.appspot.com/scan to call Barcode Scanner from a WebApp, but I can't get it to work. Even after needlessly updating and reinstalling it, all it does is show the default zxing webpage that asks me to install Barcode Scanner on my phone. Am I missing something?

Here's the javascript I'm using to call ZXing Scanner. For test purposes, I've even tried to make a simple HTML hyperlink, without success. I'm using Android's `WebView` to load the app.

```
window.location.href = 
"http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http://192.168.1.33:3000/pallet/{CODE}/change_position/"+positionId+"&SCAN_FORMATS=CODE_39";
```

And this is the Barcode Scanner's manifest that identifies and triggers the scanner through browser:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="zxing.appspot.com" android:path="/scan"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Funny thing is, `http://www.google.com/m/products/scan`, that does the same thing, works perfectly. Any help or idea is very welcome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're sending a URL to an image on your local network (the 192.168... IP address), which zxing.appspot.com won't be able to access over the Internet.

Comment: I just tried that directly from the android browser, such as `http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http://www.facebook.com/{CODE}` and still it didn't trigger the scanner...
Looking at Barcode Scanner's manifest, I've identified the part where it should identify and launch the Scanner:
`<data android:scheme="http" android:host="zxing.appspot.com" android:path="/scan"/>`

This should launch the app, even if the phone is not connected to the Internet, right?

Comment: @Mecer I don't know anything about Android programming, so unfortunately I can't help with that part. Hopefully someone who knows about that can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I think I gave some thoughts on the project mailing list, but had another bright idea:

Are you sure you haven't 'saved' your preference for handling this link in the browser? For example when you have a choice of app you're typically asked whether you want to use that app forever to open that kind of link or Intent. Maybe you did that for this link only, and Browser. Go to Applications and "Clear defaults" for all these apps and try again.

Comment: I've tried with different browsers and phones, neither worked, and neither had any default set..

Answer (score 1):

Yes trigger it like this:

```
zxing://scan/?ret=http://192.168.2.9/stock/add.php?barcode={CODE}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works from the default android browser but not the google chrome browser for me

Comment: Hi @rigyt , We are also facing the same problem. Did you find the resolution this issue?

Comment: Hi yes it works fine now from Google Chrome on Android using: http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=https<my_web_app_url>/{CODE}&SCAN_FORMATS=UPC_A,EAN_13

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my input using this from HTML anchor element inside Angular 2+ app:

1. ret part of the link needs to be urlencoded so just use

```js
 this.callbackUrl = encodeURIComponent(`${currentURL}{CODE}&SCAN_FORMATS=Code 39`);
 this.totalBarCodeUrl = `http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=${this.callbackUrl}`;
```

2. HTML be like:

```html
 <a [href]="totalBarCodeUrl"></a>
```